# CSRF token missing error using vue-recaptcha and a Django Rest Framework middleware

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, recaptcha, csrf-token

I have the following setup :

- a frontend app developed with VueJS on which I have a registration form component, including few standard fields, a mandatory checkbox (user agreement), and a Google Recaptcha V2 (vue-recaptcha) checkbox
- a backend API developed with Django Rest Framework, with a specific route to request Google Recaptcha web service (using `rest_framework_recaptcha` application)

Route declaration in `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('recaptcha_verify/', RecaptchaVerifyView.as_view(), name='recaptcha_verify'),
    ...
]
```

DRF view :

```py
class RecaptchaVerifyView(APIView):
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ReCaptchaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Simple serializer based on `rest_framework_recaptcha`:

```py
from rest_framework_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class ReCaptchaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = ReCaptchaField()
```

Frontend VueJS component :

```js
<v-form>
  <v-checkbox
    v-model="consentCheckbox"
    :rules="[rules.required]"
  >  
    <template v-slot:label>
      <div>User agreement message</div>
    </template>
  </v-checkbox>

  <div align="center">
    <vue-recaptcha 
      ref="recaptcha"
      @verify="onVerify"
      :sitekey="sitekey"
      :loadRecaptchaScript="true"
    >
     </vue-recaptcha>
  </div>
</v-form>
```

And the methods associated to the component (`handleRegister` is called when the submit button is clicked) :

```js
onVerify(response) {
  this.message = false;
  this.recaptchaResponse = response;
  this.recaptchaVerified = true;
},
async handleRegister() {
  // Check if recaptcha has been ticked
  if (!this.recaptchaVerified) {
    return true; // prevent form from submitting
  }
  else if ( this.$refs.form.validate() ) {
    // Check recaptcha by calling backend (DRF) specific route (itself calling Google API)
    var response = await RecaptchaService
                        .verifyRecaptcha(this.recaptchaResponse)
                        .catch(error => this.message = (error.response && error.response.data) || error.message || error.toString());
    if (response.data.success) {
      // process
    }
}
```

Finally, the VueJS service dedicated to calling recaptcha API on backend:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_HOST_NAME + '/api/v1/accounts/';

class RecaptchaService {
    async verifyRecaptcha(token) {
        return axios.post(API_URL + 'recaptcha_verify/', 
        {
            token: token,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          //catch error
        }
```

I don't have any issue working in a development environment (frontend and backend accessible on localhost). Yet, when deployed in production (with https enabled), I face the following problem:

- Checking the user agreement checkbox first, *then* the Recaptcha works fine
- Checking the Recaptcha *then* the user agreement returned a 403 Forbidden error, with the message `CSRF token missing or incorrect`
- Once I get the previous error, I always get the error when filling the form again, no matter the order of checking boxes

I don't get why:

1. the problem does not occur on localhost
2. the order of filling form lead to different behaviours
3. the problem only occurs on my registration form while I do have several other forms (login, sending data, etc.) that work fine

Any ideas to help me understand/investigate the problem ? I have read many posts related to Django and CSRF or CORS related issues but they are often related to django templates or SessionAuthentication.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to guess the problem without seeing the code.

However, since localhost works maybe the base url in production in your frontend is not `https://` but `http://`.

Comment: My base url in production does have the https scheme. I can add some code snippets in my question, but I wasn't sure what pieces are relevant ? API view, serializer ? Frontend component or service ?

Comment: I understand very well that it is difficult to know what to look at and you cannot post all the code. I tried to guess because I happened to change the url in `settings.py`, but forget to add `https` to the base url in frontend.  
Instead of the code you could try to report the errors that appear in console.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway :) I only get one error which is the 403 Forbidden error when POSTing data to my route dedicated to recaptcha `https://example.com/backend/api/v1/accounts/recaptcha_verify/` with the following response body : `detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."`

Comment: I have added many code snippets to give an overview of the setup and what might go wrong with my code